# Is choosing a subset to maximize the average its members, an NP hard problem?

Tags: np-hardness

Given a set of real numbers, choose a subset to maximize the average subject to the average not exceeding a given threshold. Is it NP hard?

I think so, but I cannot come out with a proof. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

This is at least as hard as the Subset Sum problem, hence, yes it is NP-hard.

Comment: Any suggestions for a rigorous proof? Thanks much!

Comment: Hint: for nonempty $S$, $\textrm{average}(S) \leq 0 \leftrightarrow \textrm{sum}(S)\leq 0$.

Comment: Can you give more hint please? I do not know how to handle the cardinality $|S|$.